# Older Phone Models Less Secure?

Tags: phone

Are older phone models inherently less secure than newer ones assuming you're still able to run the latest software?

I am pecifically curious about older models of iPhones (e.g. ~2015 ish)

Comment: Newer software is not by definition more secure software. Although it often contains but fixes, it also may introduce new features and new vulnerabilities. It’s hard to give a generic answer to this question without being specific which software and hardware you’re comparing.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, having the latest software is going to at least protect you from issues affecting older software. However, it may not always be possible to update drivers or firmware that is unique to the older device, especially if they include proprietary blobs. That said, attacks against these components are less likely unless you are specifically targeted by someone with serious resources.

You may also miss out if the newer devices have security-related hardware modules, secure boot support, harder-to-unlock bootloaders etc., things that are helpful to defense-in-depth in certain scenarios.

Comment: Mobile devices don't usually have TPMs, but they do have analogous secure hardware components under different names.